# Early Middle English diphthongs

Tags: english, phonology, historical-linguistics

Wikipedia has a helpful page on [Middle English phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_English_phonology): but there are two diphthongs in its table which I cannot identify: the close-mid diphthongs “`/oi/`, developing into `/ui/`” and “`/ei/`, developing into `/i:/`”.

Which words had these sounds?

[image: table of Middle English diphthongs]

Comment: FWIW Blackwell’s *A History of English* doesn’t seem to list those, only the open-mid /ɛɪ/ /ɔɪ/.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I found the (partial) answer in the same page: early /ei/, the result of e + a palatalized g, merged into /i:/ early. It was found in words like eye (OE ēage > ēġe > eye), to lie, meaning to deceive (OE lēogan > lēġan > to lie) and fly OE (flēoge > flēġe > fly)

I didn’t find out which words had /oi/, but I suppose it was just a transitional state of borrowed Oïl /oi/, before it was shifted to /ui̯/, and placed in table twice, by mistake.